# Excel to Google Sheet: Same Formula not working

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a sales project and I'm in need of help. I've been working on my project in Excel and all formulas were made in it but management asked me to upload it online on Sheets so everyone can access it.

What I'm doing is making table for all workers and their leads. I'm making 3 commumns, Success %, Total success and Total leads overall.

I've been counting it in Excel this way for total overall and that's also a point where Sheets are not helping me out.

```
=IFS(AND($Q$2="Week",$Q$3="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000,Variabelen!$D$33:$I$33,Data!$J$2:$J$20000,$P7)),AND($Q$2="Maand",$Q$3="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000,Variabelen!$D$33:$I$33,Data!$K$2:$K$20000,$P7)),AND($Q$2="Quarter",$Q$3="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000,Variabelen!$D$33:$I$33,Data!$L$2:$L$20000,$P7)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adwXR.png)

Whereas I'm taking all info from Data, Variables are what's counting the leads statuses (such as open, not available, finished etc) and I'm also making it changable depending if I wanna see based on Week/Month/Quarter. In the excel this is correctly counting all leads depending on what I choose but whenever I import it onto sheets, its not working.

Thing I noticed that is not working is this part (highlighted)

=IFS(AND($Q$2="Week",$Q$3="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000,**Variabelen!$D$33:$I$33**,Data!$J$2:$J$20000,$P7))

When I actually write it in the sheet with updated naming only, formula itself is same it gives me this.

```
=IFS(AND($AG$5="Week",$AG$6="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000,$D$33:$I$33,Data!$J$2:$J$20000,$AF9)),AND($AG5="Maand",$AG$6="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000, $D$33:$I$33,Data!$K$2:$K$20000,$AF9)),AND($AG$5="Kwartaal",$AG$6="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000,$D$33:$I$33,Data!$L$2:$L$20000,$AF9)))
```

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRENL.png)

I noticed that for some reason it won't count array as criteria in countif in the sheets and it's forcing me to manually write 5 formulas and then 6th to count them all together to get total.

EDIT:
=IFS(AND($AG$5="Week",$AG$6="Bedrijf"),SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$I$2:$I$20000,**$D$33**,Data!$J$2:$J$20000,$AF9)).....
After getting rid of the array in criteria, it's working for only one condition rather than all that I selected.
[example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO4vS.png)

I did my best to explain the issue and I'd be glad to receive any possible solution to my issue. My suspicion is that in Excel Countif can count array as criteria whereas in Sheets it won't.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Excel and Googlesheets are not the same. Some functions exist in both and are identical. Other functions exist but are not identical ie they have arguments in different positions. Some functions just don't exist in both. So check what does not work and then re-write the function - as you know the logic then it should not be a problem.

Comment: Use helper cells to do the countif() instead of countifs() then use those results?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Thank you Solar Mike, your suggestion helped and fixed my issue